# Monitor buttons stop working after DDC/CI control

Tags: display, external-display

I was using this [ddcctl](https://github.com/kfix/ddcctl) to control my Xiaomi 34" monitor via command line.

Everything was fine when I was just running commands like:

```
ddcctl -d 1 -b 30 (to change brightness to 30, works fine)
ddcctl -d 1 -i 15 (to change input source, doesn't work though)
```

All that time I could still use the physical monitor buttons to switch input source.

But later on, when I was experimenting with other flags from that library, I tried:

```
ddcctl -d 1 -p 1 (also tried with value 2 and 3, this is supposed to control the power On/Off)
```

as well as

```
ddcctl -d 1 -m 0 (and 1, this is to mute/unmute monitor)
```

Right after executing those commands, pressing the physical buttons on my monitor will no longer open up the menu, but it will force restart the monitor (go blank, auto detect input source, then display as normal).

I have tried [softMCCS](https://www.entechtaiwan.com/lib/softmccs.shtm) to factory reset the monitor, but I guess those only affect the color settings. The issue remains.

Is there any way to hard reset my monitor?

Answer (score 0):

I've had issues with DDC control of my Xiaomi monitor as well.  I don't think they implemented DDC properly.  Stuck with it unless they release a new firmware that we can somehow flash, I guess.